# NoClassDefFoundError in lower versions of android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting this error while running the app in android os 4.3 API 18, but works fine if it is on os 5.1.0 API 22

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:289)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.webakruti.soilreport.model.LoginResponse not present
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getRawType(ImplForType.java:64)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:73)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:61)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:53)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:72)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:29)
at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:761)
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:82)
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.
<init>
(TypeToken.java:62)
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity$2.
<init>
(LoginActivity.java:79)
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:79)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.webakruti.soilreport.model.LoginResponse
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getRawType(ImplForType.java:62)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:73) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:61) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:53) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:72) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:29) 
at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:761) 
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:82) 
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.
<init>
(TypeToken.java:62) 
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity$2.
<init>
(LoginActivity.java:79) 
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:79) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/webakruti/soilreport/model/LoginResponse
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getRawType(ImplForType.java:62) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:73) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:61) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:53) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:72) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:29) 
at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:761) 
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:82) 
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.
<init>
(TypeToken.java:62) 
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity$2.
<init>
(LoginActivity.java:79) 
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:79) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webakruti.soilreport.model.LoginResponse" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.webakruti.soilreport-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.webakruti.soilreport-2, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getRawType(ImplForType.java:62) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:73) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:61) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:53) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType.getResolvedType(ImplForType.java:72) 
at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.Types.getType(Types.java:29) 
at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:761) 
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:82) 
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.
<init>
(TypeToken.java:62) 
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity$2.
<init>
(LoginActivity.java:79) 
at com.webakruti.soilreport.ui.activities.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:79) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The java code

```
   public void login(View v) {
    email = edtLogin.getText().toString();
    pwd = edtPassword.getText().toString();

    postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
    postParam.put("username", email);
    postParam.put("password", pwd);
    postParam.put("grant_type", "password");

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(postParam);
    Type type = new TypeToken<LoginResponse>() {
   }.getType();
    // GeneralRequest.login(LoginActivity.this, type, object, LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.this);
    callApi(postParam);
}

XML where the method is called:
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_400"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="login"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_corner"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />
```

GRADLE APP FILE-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.soilreport"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.3'
compile files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar')
}
```

Things i have tried so far:

1. Restarted android studio
2. Restarted geny motion
3. Restarted my laptop.
4. Cloned the project again
5. Checked for the java version and gradle version
6. Uninstalled the apk and installed again
7. Checked the initialization of all the variables

Can anyone please explain why i have an issue with this build file ?

Comment: put your `Onclick()` method code..........

Comment: Posted the code too, hope you can help me

Comment: Main error is this: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.webakruti.soilreport.model.LoginResponse" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.webakruti.soilreport-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.webakruti.soilreport-2, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)`

Comment: I guess class not found is because of some missing libraries, i have checked if i am missing any of them, none of them are missing, is there any other reason why i might be facing this issue ?

Comment: Share your Gradle file and any jars you have in the libs folder

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

public void login(View v) {
email = edtLogin.getText().toString();
pwd = edtPassword.getText().toString();

postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
postParam.put("username", email);
postParam.put("password", pwd);
postParam.put("grant_type", "password");

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(postParam);
Type type = new TypeToken<LoginResponse>() {
}.getType();
// GeneralRequest.login(LoginActivity.this, type, object,  LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.this);
callApi(postParam);
}

//activity oncreated method and other override methods

}
```

here notice one thing that I have shown you that you should put your onclick method inside your activity but outside of "@override" method because those are activity generated methods.